# Full Disk Encryption in existing Linux system without erasing any content from the drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, disk-encryption

I am trying to achieve "Full Disk Encryption" in a already installed Linux system. I have come across with LUKS with dm-crypt, it can encrypt a drive/entire disk, but before encrypting it is formatting the drive first and all data is getting removed permanently.

As I need to do "Full Disk Encryption" for an existing & mature Linux machine(e.g Ubuntu, centOS), I cannot possibly afford the formatting of the drives/partitions. Is there any possible method by which I can do the "Full Disk Encryption" without loosing the existing contents in the system.

I am very new to these concepts so any proper guidance will be of great help.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to shrink your partition by 1028 KB (slightly more than 1 MB). I would recommend to shrink it by 4 MB. Unmount your partition before the operation.

For ext4:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdd1|grep 'Block count'
```

substract 1024 from this value (assuming you have 4KB blocks), then do:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdd1 new_value
```

Then encrypt it:

```
sudo cryptsetup-reencrypt -N --reduce-device-size 4M /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: This should be marked as an answer!  I verify these steps work for encrypting an existing ext4 file system (not root). Note that the ETA was only available after `cryptsetup-reencrypt` was executed, almost 8 hours in my case. Make sure you can leave your system undisturbed for a while on large partitions:
`Finished, time 468:50.978, 953864 MiB written, speed  33.9 MiB/s`  

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182387/how-to-mount-a-disk-encrypted-with-cryptsetupcrypto-luks-in-ubuntu-14-04) for mounting instructions.

Comment: "assuming you have 4KB blocks" — don't assume that. Look at the value for "Block size" in the `dumpe2fs` output.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to quick mind:

1. Install cryptsetup-reencrypt. Use the flags you need/desire to reencrypt it  (this ONLY  messes with the LUKS Device not the underlying Filesystem (fs) whatever it is ext2/3/4, xfs,  etc).
2. BACKUP everything when unlocked (booted and running) or as a mounted `dd` or `rsync` option to a second drive then rebuild as desired.